# Can VLANs with same no but on different switches communicate with each other?

Tags: cisco, vlan, switching, switchport

If i have a VLAN (say VLAN 10) on switch 1 and again a VLAN 10 on switch 2. Can the hosts on these VLANS communicate with each other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, assuming the switches are connected together and VLAN 10 is forwarding on the connected ports.  Both ports have to be configured the same, so that VLAN 10 is either tagged on both or untagged (native) on both.

Comment: May also be helpful to mention this is why documentation of what VLAN's carry what meanings are important: misconfiguration can have serious security consequences. (Naming, as an example, is extremely important.)

Answer (score 0):

yes, however they must be conected with a trunk link and allowed the same vlan's, don't forget to set the link as trunk

Comment: They don't have to be trunks.  Consider an access port set to vlan 10 on both switches.

Comment: XD cisco cries right now, but what happened to good practices and recommendations?

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say, but it's not a universal rule.  And especially for a student who is trying to learn the concept, it's more important that they understand when tagging matters and when it doesn't.

Comment: Excuse me if I was rude, I just tried to teach the right way, how companies will demand it in the workplace

Comment: It is certainly a best practice to connect switches with trunk links, even if there is only a single VLAN between them, but it is also not a requirement, and I see companies connect switches with access interfaces all the time. The most current best practice is to limit a VLAN to a single access switch, and never connect access switches to each other.

Comment: No offense taken. I believe understanding the technology comes first. Then you can provide guidance on good practices.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments certainly they are of real value

Answer (score 0):

Yes ! Vlan 10 connected host on different switch communicate each other . But following Configuration is required on switches

1. Ensure both switch connected with access ports and allow Vlan 10

**In Switch1**

`Swith1(config)#int ethernet 0/0`

`Switch1(config)#switchport mode access`

`Switch1(config)#switchport access vlan 10`

`Switch1(config)#no shutdown`

**Switch2**

`Swith2(config)#int ethernet 0/0`

`Switch2(config)#switchport mode access`

`Switch2(config)#switchport access vlan 10`

`Switch2(config)#no shutdown`

2. Create Vlan 10 on both switches